# Parsing input from csv file to char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

My csv file is formatted this way:

```
0,0,46,#FFFFFF,#000000
```

I want to store the data this way:

```
typedef struct {
    char x[2];
    char y[2];
    char asc[3];
    char fore[7];
    char back[7];
}LINE;
```

The function i made for parsing each line is like:

```
LINE ParseLine(){
char c;
int i=0;
LINE Linea;

    i=0;
    c=fgetc(Archivo);
    while (c!=','){
        Linea.x[i]=c;
        i++;
        c=fgetc(Archivo);
    }
    Linea.x[i]='\0';

    i=0;
    c=fgetc(Archivo);
    while (c!=','){
        Linea.y[i]=c;
        i++;
        c=fgetc(Archivo);
    }
    Linea.y[i]='\0';

    i=0;
    c=fgetc(Archivo);
    while (c!=','){
        Linea.asc[i]=c;
        i++;
        c=fgetc(Archivo);
    }
    Linea.asc[i]='\0';

    i=0;
    c=fgetc(Archivo);
    while (c!=','){
        Linea.fore[i]=c;
        i++;
        c=fgetc(Archivo);
    }
    Linea.fore[i]='\0';

    i=0;
    c=fgetc(Archivo);
    while (c!='\n'){
        Linea.back[i]=c;
        i++;
        c=fgetc(Archivo);
    }
    Linea.back[i]='\0';

    //Show values
    printf("%s\t%d\n",Linea.x,strlen(Linea.x));
    printf("%s\t%d\n",Linea.y,strlen(Linea.y));
    printf("%s\t%d\n",Linea.asc,strlen(Linea.asc));
    printf("%s\t%d\n",Linea.fore,strlen(Linea.fore));
    printf("%s\t%d\n",Linea.back,strlen(Linea.back));
    return Linea;
```

}

Everything is okay until Linea.fore , in the output, Linea.fore shows "#FFFFFF#000000" and its strlen is 14, like the while loop never found the "," that separated those values. But Linea.back have both its value and len all right.

I think this is a problem about char array handling.

- Why the problem only shows in Linea.fore?
- Should i use for loops instead of while loops and ask for the ','inside the loop?
- it's hardcoding '\0' wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Neither `fore` nor `back` are large enough to store seven characters and a null terminator.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following the same logic, according to which your defined

```
char x[2];
char y[2];
```

you'll need

```
char fore[8];
char back[8];
```

to store the full array (as per your input) with null-termination.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! 

I just forget to add 1 char to the '\0' in the declaration of the type and that was giving me some problems haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the \0-terminator on the *fore* field, so the strlen en printf functions see the *fore* and *back* fields together.